# Verilog - Quartus compilation error after compiling FPGA Rom

Tags: verilog, fpga

For an uni's project I should print a maze in FPGA, the data should be first written in a ROM and then be read from it. From 32 bit data I get them in teams of 2 and based on their encoding I give them some specific color.

When I run my code in quartus I get compilation error:

> Error: "can't resolve multiple constant drivers".

My code for the rom is this:

```
module thirdLab(

  input logic clk,
  input logic rst,
  input logic [3:0] address,
  output logic [31:0] data,
  output logic hsync,
  output logic vsync,
  output logic [3:0] red,
  output logic [3:0] green,
  output logic [3:0] blue);


  logic half_clock;
  logic [9:0] x;
  logic [9:0] y;


  //Decision help variables.
  logic [1:0] decBits0;
  logic [1:0] decBits1;
  logic [1:0] decBits2;
  logic [1:0] decBits3;
  logic [1:0] decBits4;
  logic [1:0] decBits5;
  logic [1:0] decBits6;
  logic [1:0] decBits7;
  logic [1:0] decBits8;
  logic [1:0] decBits9;
  logic [1:0] decBits10;
  logic [1:0] decBits11;
  logic [1:0] decBits12;
  logic [1:0] decBits13;
  logic [1:0] decBits14;
  logic [1:0] decBits15;


  always_ff @(posedge clk)
  begin
   if(!rst)
     half_clock <=0;
   else
      if(half_clock)
       half_clock <=0;
      else
       half_clock <=1;
  end


  always_ff @(posedge clk)
  begin
   if(!rst)
     x <=0;
   else
     if (half_clock)
       if (x==799)
         x <= 0;
       else
         x <= x+1;
  end


  always_ff @(posedge clk)
  begin
   if(!rst)
     y <=0;
   else
     if (half_clock)
       if (x==799)
         if (y==523)
           y <=0;
         else
           y <= y+1;
  end


  always_comb
  begin
   if (x>=655 && x<752)
     hsync =0;
   else
     hsync =1;
   if (y>=490 && y<493)
     vsync =0;
   else
     vsync =1;
  end


  //Initialize rom memory.
  always_comb
  begin
  case (address)

    4'b0000: data = 32'b00_00_01_10_00_00_00_01_00_01_00_00_01_01_01_00;
    4'b0001: data = 32'b00_00_01_00_00_00_00_01_01_01_00_01_00_00_01_00;
    4'b0011: data = 32'b01_00_00_00_00_00_00_00_01_00_00_01_00_00_01_00;
    4'b0100: data = 32'b00_01_00_00_00_00_00_01_00_00_01_01_01_01_01_01;
    4'b0101: data = 32'b00_00_01_00_00_00_00_00_00_00_00_01_00_01_01_01;
    4'b0110: data = 32'b01_01_01_01_01_01_01_01_01_00_00_01_00_00_00_00;
    4'b0111: data = 32'b00_01_01_00_01_01_00_01_00_01_00_00_00_00_01_00;
    4'b1000: data = 32'b01_00_01_01_00_00_01_01_01_00_00_01_00_00_01_00;
    4'b1001: data = 32'b11_00_00_00_00_01_01_01_01_00_00_01_01_00_01_00;
    4'b1010: data = 32'b00_00_01_00_01_00_01_01_01_01_00_00_00_00_01_00;
    4'b1011: data = 32'b01_01_01_00_10_00_00_01_01_01_00_01_01_01_01_00;
    default: data = 32'b00_01_01_00_00_00_00_00_01_00_00_01_00_00_01_00;

    endcase
  end

  //Internal memory, accessed through address only.
  reg [31:0] mem [12];

  always_ff @(posedge clk)
  begin

  data <= mem[address];
  decBits0 <= data[1:0];
  decBits1 <= data[3:2];
  decBits2 <= data[5:4];
  decBits3 <= data[7:6];
  decBits4 <= data[9:8];
  decBits5 <= data[11:10];
  decBits6 <= data[13:12];
  decBits7 <= data[15:14];
  decBits8 <= data[17:16];
  decBits9 <= data[19:18];
  decBits10 <= data[21:20];
  decBits11 <= data[23:22];
  decBits12 <= data[25:24];
  decBits13 <= data[27:26];
  decBits14 <= data[29:28];
  decBits15 <= data[31:30];

  end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Multiple Constant Drivers" Error Verilog with Quartus Prime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40879790/multiple-constant-drivers-error-verilog-with-quartus-prime)

Answer (score 1):

"Multiple driver" error messages means you are driving the same signal in two different places. In two always blocks, or in two assigns or, in system Verilog, an always block and an assign.

Normally the compiler error message should tell you where the error occurs. But I don't know Quartus so maybe that is not the case.

You must look at each variable in your code and check where you assign a value to it and then check if you also assign a value in a different place (In a different always or in an assign).

I did that with your code and found that the variable **data** is assigned a value in two different always blocks.