# Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers and Error (10029): Constant driver

Tags: error-handling, verilog, quartus, intel-fpga

I am new to Verilog, and trying to write a traffic light code where the LED light changes after certain time. I'm keep getting on different errors while compiling. I tried to fix them by changing the arrangement, or variables in the code, but it still fails.

This is the code I wrote,

```
module traffic_light(clk, reset, G1, Y1, R1, G2, Y2, R2);
input clk, reset;
output reg G1, Y1, R1, G2, Y2, R2;

// parameters for each light control
parameter GREEN = 3'b001,
             YELLOW = 3'b010,
             RED = 3'b100,
             LEFT_GREEN = 3'b101,   // assume both red and green will be turned on
             LEFT_YELLOW = 3'b110;  // assume both red and yellow will be turned on
             
// finite-state definition (Moore Type):
//                          ---------------------------
//                               NSlight          EWlight
//                          ---------------------------
parameter S0 = 3'd0, //  GREEN           RED
             S1 = 3'd1, //  YELLOW           RED
             S2 = 3'd2, // RED, GREEN        RED
             S3 = 3'd3, // RED, YELLOW       RED
             S4 = 3'd4, //      RED        GREEN
             S5 = 3'd5, //      RED       YELLOW
             S6 = 3'd6, //      RED     RED, GREEN
             S7 = 3'd7; //      RED     RED, YELLOW

// internal state variables
reg [2:0] state, next_state;

integer t1 = 19, t2 = 4;
integer count;

// buttons are appropriate for use as clock or reset inputs in a circuit
always @(posedge clk, negedge reset)
    if(reset == 'b0) // button pressed, when reset is active low
        begin
            next_state = S0;
            count = t1;
        end
    else
        state <= next_state;
        
always @(next_state)
    begin
        next_state = S0;
        count = t1;
        
        case(state)
            S0:
                if (count < 0) // load: if the count reaches below 0, reset
                    begin
                        count <= t2;
                        next_state <= S1;
                    end
                else // enable
                    begin
                        // down count
                        count <= count - 1;
                        // assign LEDs
                        G1 <= 1;
                        Y1 <= 0;
                        R1 <= 0;
                        G2 <= 0;
                        Y2 <= 0;
                        R2 <= 1;
                    end
            
            S1:
                if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t1;
                        next_state <= S2;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 0;
                        Y1 <= 1;
                        R1 <= 0;
                        G2 <= 0;
                        Y2 <= 0;
                        R2 <= 1;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
                    
            S2:
                if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t2;
                        next_state <= S3;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 1;
                        Y1 <= 0;
                        R1 <= 1;
                        G2 <= 0;
                        Y2 <= 0;
                        R2 <= 1;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
                    
            S3:
                if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t1;
                        next_state <= S4;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 0;
                        Y1 <= 1;
                        R1 <= 1;
                        G2 <= 0;
                        Y2 <= 0;
                        R2 <= 1;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
            
            S4:
                if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t1;
                        next_state <= S5;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 0;
                        Y1 <= 0;
                        R1 <= 1;
                        G2 <= 1;
                        Y2 <= 0;
                        R2 <= 0;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
                    
            S5:
                if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t1;
                        next_state <= S6;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 0;
                        Y1 <= 0;
                        R1 <= 1;
                        G2 <= 0;
                        Y2 <= 1;
                        R2 <= 0;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
                    
            S6:
                if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t2;
                        next_state <= S7;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 0;
                        Y1 <= 0;
                        R1 <= 1;
                        G2 <= 1;
                        Y2 <= 0;
                        R2 <= 1;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
            
            S7:
                if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t1;
                        next_state <= S0;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 0;
                        Y1 <= 0;
                        R1 <= 1;
                        G2 <= 0;
                        Y2 <= 1;
                        R2 <= 1;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
                
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

and these are the errors generated from the above code:

Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "next_state.S0" at traffic_light.v(41)

Error (10029): Constant driver at traffic_light.v(32)

Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "next_state.S1" at traffic_light.v(41)

Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "next_state.S2" at traffic_light.v(41)

Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "next_state.S3" at traffic_light.v(41)

Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "next_state.S6" at traffic_light.v(41)

Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "next_state.S7" at traffic_light.v(41)

Error (12152): Can't elaborate user hierarchy "traffic_light:inst"

Hope I can get any suggestions or solutions to this problem. Thank you in advance.

---

I solved the problem after few more searching.

[Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net... VHDL ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061596/error-10028-cant-resolve-multiple-constant-drivers-for-net-vhdl-error)

["Multiple Constant Drivers" Error Verilog with Quartus Prime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40879790/multiple-constant-drivers-error-verilog-with-quartus-prime)

These two links helped solving, the problem is that you cannot assign one variable in two different always block.
The below code is the fixed one.

```
module traffic_light(clk, reset, G1, Y1, R1, G2, Y2, R2, time_);
input clk, reset;
output reg G1, Y1, R1, G2, Y2, R2;
output reg [4:0] time_; // added, it displays the remaining time

// parameters for each light control
parameter GREEN = 3'b001,
             YELLOW = 3'b010,
             RED = 3'b100,
             LEFT_GREEN = 3'b101,   // assume both red and green will be turned on
             LEFT_YELLOW = 3'b110;  // assume both red and yellow will be turned on
             
// finite-state definition (Moore Type):
//                          ---------------------------
//                               NSlight          EWlight
//                          ---------------------------
parameter S0 = 3'd0, //  GREEN           RED
             S1 = 3'd1, //  YELLOW           RED
             S2 = 3'd2, // RED, GREEN        RED
             S3 = 3'd3, // RED, YELLOW       RED
             S4 = 3'd4, //      RED        GREEN
             S5 = 3'd5, //      RED       YELLOW
             S6 = 3'd6, //      RED     RED, GREEN
             S7 = 3'd7; //      RED     RED, YELLOW

// internal state variables and time settings
reg [2:0] state, next_state;
integer t1 = 19, t2 = 4;
reg count; // changed to count only

always @(posedge clk)
    if(reset == 0) // button pressed, when reset is active low
        begin
            state <= S0;
            time_ <= t1;
        end
    else
        begin
            state <= next_state;
            time_ <= count;
        end

always @(*) // changed according to advice in the comment
    case(state)
        S0:     if (count < 0) // load: if the count reaches below 0, reset
                    begin
                        count <= t2;
                        next_state <= S1;
                    end
                else // enable
                    begin
                        // down count
                        count <= count - 1;
                        // assign LEDs
                        G1 <= 1;
                        Y1 <= 0;
                        R1 <= 0;
                        G2 <= 0;
                        Y2 <= 0;
                        R2 <= 1;
                    end
                    
        S1:     if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t1;
                        next_state <= S2;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 0;
                        Y1 <= 1;
                        R1 <= 0;
                        G2 <= 0;
                        Y2 <= 0;
                        R2 <= 1;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
            
                
        S2:     if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t2;
                        next_state <= S3;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 1;
                        Y1 <= 0;
                        R1 <= 1;
                        G2 <= 0;
                        Y2 <= 0;
                        R2 <= 1;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
                
        S3: if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t1;
                        next_state <= S4;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 0;
                        Y1 <= 1;
                        R1 <= 1;
                        G2 <= 0;
                        Y2 <= 0;
                        R2 <= 1;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
            
        S4:     if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t2;
                        next_state <= S5;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 0;
                        Y1 <= 0;
                        R1 <= 1;
                        G2 <= 1;
                        Y2 <= 0;
                        R2 <= 0;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
                
        S5: if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t1;
                        next_state <= S6;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 0;
                        Y1 <= 0;
                        R1 <= 1;
                        G2 <= 0;
                        Y2 <= 1;
                        R2 <= 0;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
            
        S6: if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t2;
                        next_state <= S7;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 0;
                        Y1 <= 0;
                        R1 <= 1;
                        G2 <= 1;
                        Y2 <= 0;
                        R2 <= 1;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
        
        S7: if (count < 0)
                    begin
                        count <= t1;
                        next_state <= S0;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        G1 <= 0;
                        Y1 <= 0;
                        R1 <= 1;
                        G2 <= 0;
                        Y2 <= 1;
                        R2 <= 1;
                        count <= count - 1;
                    end
                
        default:
            begin
                next_state <= S0;
                count <= t1;
            end
            
    endcase
endmodule
```

Comment: Unrelated to your errors, but *always @(next_state)* is not the best sensitivity list you can come up with. Nowadays you can just type always @(*)

Comment: Thank you. Changing to always @(*) reduced the number of error:)

Comment: There are at least the following issues within your code: 1) incorrect multiple drivers, as messages suggest. 2) zero-delay loop caused by the next_state, 2) incorrect use of blocking and non-blocking assignments; 4) incorrect style for coding the  state machine.  You need to read about those things and start your verilog coding with simpler examples.

Answer (score -1):

You have `next_state` assigned in both processes, and that is causing troubles. We can find it actually described in the [Verilog Standard](https://www.eg.bucknell.edu/%7Ecsci320/2016-fall/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/verilog-std-1364-2005.pdf). section **14.5 Driving wired logic**

> Module path output nets shall not have more than one driver within the module. Therefore, wired logic is not allowed at module path outputs

And it also provides an example:

[image]